# Не фиксированное количество выходных результатов

Tags: нейронные-сети

Скажите пожалуйста, как вот в НС на Keras реализуется динамическое количество выходных результатов. Ну вот например распознавание объектов на изображении, в принципе НС можно заставить искать один объект без проблем (наверное) и чтобы на выходе были координаты top-left и top-right нашего распознанного объекта, но вот, что делать когда у нас несколько объектов? O_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Современные алгоритмы поиска и распознования объектов на изображениях состоят из двух основных частей:

1. поиск рамок (`boundary boxes`) обрамляющих объект (может существовать несколько вариантов обрамления одного объекта (например в R-CNN), впоследствие выбирается оптимальный вариант)
2. классификация объектов в найденных рамках

Некоторые алгоритмы умеют делать все сразу за один проход, например [YOLO (You Only Look Once)](https://towardsdatascience.com/yolo-you-only-look-once-real-time-object-detection-explained-492dc9230006).

Все описанные выше ИНС (Искусственные Нейронные Сети) умеют распознавать строго определенное количество объектов - те объекты, которые присутствовали в обучающей выборке изображений. Большинство успешных архитектур обучались на свободно доступном наборе картинок - ImageNet, например - [Large Scale Visual Recognition Challenge 2017 (ILSVRC2017)](http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2017/), состоящей из 150.000 фотографий (для обучения и проверки), содердащих 1000 категорий заведомо размеченных объектов.

Поэтому число определяемых объектов фиксировано набором размеченных объектов/категорий из обучающей выборки.

Comment: Так :), малость уточню свою мысль-вопрос, буду опираться от вашего первого пункта, вот если мы будем строить обычную (многослойный перцептрон) НС, то у нас на выходе будет два параметра-координаты top-left и top-right для определения рамКИ, но не рамОК, а как вот определять несколько рамОК? )))

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, это имеет мало общего с многослойным перцептроном. Если хотите разобраться как это работает, то советую пройти курс [Convolutional Neural Networks
by deeplearning.ai от проф. Andrew Ng](https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks/home/welcome) - там все очень подробно объясняется. Объяснить как работает ИНС для определения и локализации объектов, в рамках одного ответа на SO, по-моему, нереально.

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, Можете поискать на YouTube видео, объчсняющие как работает YOLO алгоритм, но у вас скорее всего возникнет много вопросов. В курсе "Convolutional Neural Networks" вас постепенно подводят к главному объясняя все "на пальцах"

Comment: а не подскажите где можно это бесплатно узнать, а то там подписку надо оформлять ?:*(

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, попробуйте поискать на YouTube- [некоторые лекции из курса легко находятся](https://m.youtube.com/results?search_query=deeplearning.ai+andrew+ng+convolutional)

Comment: Спасибо огромное  